# How to resize the designer-space in qt-creator if needed when developing?

Tags: qt, ide, qt-creator, qmainwindow

As I am putting more widgets on top of more layouts in my application, the space where I design the GUI is getting also bigger for the Qt-creator interface.

I have many buttons and frames which are out of reach. I cannot see them (or click them, of course). I don't know how they look until I run the whole application for debugging.

[image]

Is there is a way to zoom out/in the main frame (the whole playground) so that I can see my full GUI design on the UI of Qt IDE?

P.S.: I am working on macBook 13"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zooming is not possible. You can use `Tools -> Form Editor -> Preview`.

If the viewport gets too small the QtCreator shows scrollbars which allow to move the part of interest into view.

Note, on some system configurations the scollbars may be very small and hard to handle.

Comment: Thank you for the good tip to preview the form.    However, I would like to edit and design the form too.    Also, I could make the right side-panel tinier, but it would make no difference, even if I squeezed the left-panel as well ( as you can see in the updated screenshot).    In addition, the edges of the MainWindow frame is fixed.   Your answer partially helped but I'm unfortunate with the solution.

Comment: Actually, I'd expect you get a vertical scrollbar. But I can't see one on the shot. I get horizontal and vertical scrollbars if the widget doesn't fit into the viewport ..

Comment: I am not concern with the end-user. The end user will have to whole screen. He/she doesn't need the scrollers. I want the view for myself to develop and design.

Comment: Me neighter .. i get the scrollbars in the qrcreator in the designer .. enabling me to scroll to the part of the window i need to work on.

Comment: Actually I have a dialog having much more content than it will ever show when running (by hiding unnecessary widgets) but in the creator it is three screens high !

Comment: You agree with me this is not the best solution, right ? as these scroll bars must be removed later from the design. For me a better solution is not to include them because they are not part of the design. Thanks anyway for your effort to help.

Comment: you did not understand .. the qtcreater should automatically display them. like a painting tool does it when the image is to large or like word if the document needs to scrolled.

Comment: Alright, I finally got what you mean. Yes, I see the scrollbars now. But I have to stop carefully and focus on the edges of the designer by the mouse to be able to click and move them up/down or left/right. Thanks, this is not exactly what I am looking for (i.e.: zooming feature) but it is close enough. Please edit your answer include this Qt-creator feature and I will accept it.

Comment: Changed it .. so your scrollbars are very small ?

Comment: Yes, they are, really. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score -2):

You can use this steps
Tool-->options-> Text editor ->zoom

[Text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sNWI.png)